# Adding an Appointment to Multiple Calendars in Outlook

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook, outlook-addin

I am creating an outlook AddIn in Visual Studio 2010.

I have two Outlook Calendars:  1) default exchange calendar and 2) Personal Time Tracking Calendar.  I have a form region that displays account numbers to track my time to depending on the task.

What I would like to do is if the appointment is in my personal calendar, I would like to add the appointment also to my time tracking calendar.

I've tried this:

```
var outlook = new Application();
var appt = OutlookItem as AppointmentItem;

if (appt == null)
    return;

try
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbxCapNum.Text))
    {
        if (appt.UserProperties.Find(Constants.CAPITAL_NUMBER) == null)
        {
            appt.UserProperties.Add(Constants.CAPITAL_NUMBER, OlUserPropertyType.olText);
        }

        appt.UserProperties[Constants.CAPITAL_NUMBER].Value = txtbxCapNum.Text;
    }


    if (!(outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder).Name.Equals(Constants.TIME_TRACKING_CALENDAR) && chbxInclude.Checked)
    {

        GetTimeTrackingCalendar(outlook).Items.Add(appt);
    }

    appt.Save();
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Where GetTimeTrackingCalendar is defined as:

```
public static MAPIFolder GetTimeTrackingCalendar(Application outlook )
{
    MAPIFolder result = null;
    MAPIFolder calendars = (MAPIFolder)outlook.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    for (int i = 1; i <= calendars.Folders.Count; i++)
    {
        if (calendars.Folders[i].Name != Constants.TIME_TRACKING_CALENDAR) continue;
        result = calendars.Folders[i];
        break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, the save method returns the following ambiguous error:

=============================================================================

## *Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are not valid.*

Anyone know what parameter is not valid or even how to determine which parameter is invalid?

Thanks, BillN

Comment: You probably already know this, but a great tool for anyone working with programming Outlook interfaces is OutlookSpy, http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the Namerspace.Stores collection, find the store that you need and use Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) to open the default CXalendar folder of that store.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I believe I have the calendar correctly, I just can't seem to add the appointment to the calendar.

Comment: The line  (MAPIFolder)outlook.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder always returns the default calendar folder. You can also get rid of the ActiveExplorer() part.